# Inserting multiple parent rows and multiple child rows for each parent with ADO.NET in one setting

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

I am looking for a howto or someone expert in ADO.NET who can explain me how to properly solve the following scenario:

I have two datatables in a dataset:

- ParentTable (ParentID, Name) for user data
- ChildTable (ParentID, ActivityID, ...) for schedule data

Tables are linked together at the database level by `ParentID` which is an Identity column in `ParentTable`.

Both tables are data bound to a separate `DataGridView` on the GUI. There supposed to be a "1 parent/N children" relationship between the tables, meaning if I create a new entry in the `ParentTable` (a new user) I get a clean `DataGrid` in the child grid to type schedule data for the user. So I setup two `DataAdapters` for each table to fill their result into a `DataSet`. I also set up a `DataRelation` object and assign it to the `DataSet` to link the two tables by their `ParentID` columns. Also when I add a row into the `ChildTable` via `DataGrid` I use `SetParentRow` to set the parent row.

```vb
With DAUser
    .SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("UsersSelect", conn)
    .SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", MyID)
    .Fill(DSData)
End With

With DAActivity
    .SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("ActivitiesSelect", conn)
    .SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", MyID)
    .Fill(DSData)
End With

DSData.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("UserActivity", DSData.Tables(0).Columns("ParentID"), DSData.Tables(1).Columns("ParentID")))
```

Adding row into the ChildTable:

```vb
Private Sub DTChildData_TableNewRow(sender As Object, e As System.Data.DataTableNewRowEventArgs) Handles DTChildData.TableNewRow
    e.Row.SetParentRow(ParentDataRow)
End Sub
```

Still, the `ParentID` column in `ChildTable` is not populated with the Identity value retrieved from the DB when `ParentTable` is updated.

Why? I am starting to loose serious amount of hair over this problem...

Comment: There's a rename of the default Table name "Table" before the second Fill operation, so that the first table is not overwritten.
Also if I use FillSchema instead of Fill, the Dataset is not filled at all... strange

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes:

1) The relation between the two tables is most likely incorrect, since you are referencing ParentID on both sides of the relationship. I am guessing that you need to change it to:

```
DSData.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("UserActivity", DSData.Tables(0).Columns("UserID"), DSData.Tables(1).Columns("ParentID")))
```

2) You aren't showing your insert or update commands, but if they are stored procedures and the UserID is generated in that stored procedure, then you will need to pass it back out of the stored procedure as an OUTPUT parameter. You will have to change both the SP and the parameter definition (if you have one) in the insert/updated command.